# CSS Flex Column reverse - responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am building my first site and I want to use flex to reverse columns. Mobile two rows, one 100% width row with an image and then another 100% row with text. On Desktop on single row, left column 50% width text and right column 50% width image.

I was using this css code that works just fine, except I would like to follow the mobile first style and then I want the media to be from (min-width: 600px) instead of (max-width: 600px).

Currently on mobile ( less than 600px) columns are 100%, and from 600px columns are 50%.

So how do I display the code mobile-first using min-width ? As mentioned, I like on mobile columns 100% and after 600px to reverse the order and now columns are 50% on desktop.

If I switched the item property value, then on desktop columns are 50% but not on same row, one after the other, leaving a 50% space on left. So I am clueless why so are the css rules to change (max-width: 600px) to (min-width: 600px) ?

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
 }

.item {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #eeeeee;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.last {
  color: #222;
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){

 .parent {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;  
  }

 .item {
    width: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
 }

 .last {
  background: #aa0000;
 }
```

}

Comment: can u provide a rough sketch of what u want on mobile and desktop along with your html code?

Comment: I did this codepen with my code. I just wanna use a mobile first approach, then same code, but  instead to use max-width  making the changes from 600px using @ min-width. [link](https://codepen.io/tokyoweb/pen/mjGLqY)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution, It uses the mobile first approach.

Meaning, it will apply all the styles before the media query to any device,

After that it will check whether the width of screen is greater than 600px, if yes, then it will apply the styles inside media query and if not, then it will ignore the styles inside media query.

The reason you were getting te issue after switching the styles was because you were not setting the value of flex direction inside the media query

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.item {
  width: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.last {
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .parent {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .item {
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 500px;
  }

  .last {
    color: #222;
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="item last">
    <h2>Flexbox</h2>
    <p>Testing...</p>
    <p>Testing...</p>
    <p>Reduce the window size to below 600px to see an example.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item" style="background: url(https://unsplash.it/800/300) center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Naik, thanks a lot for your help ! It is just perfect ; )

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by using this on the parent...

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flex Property of reverse [**flex-direction**] with media query

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .parent{
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column-reverse;
          }
   }
```

> this media query will run only for mobile devices. and your column
> will reverse in mobile.